# Is ListLiterator a Subclass of Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I ran into this question:

I know both ListIterator and Iterator are interfaces. From Java API document, it says ListIterator extends Iterator, so that means Iterator is a subclass of Iterator right?

Answer (score 0):

ListIterator is a subclass which extends Iterator

A ListIterator allows traversal in both directions, rather than just checking if there are more elements (`hasNext()`), and getting the next one (`next()`).  It maintains a cursor position and calls to `next()` and `previous()` will alter the position and return relevant values.  ListIterator also allows the addition (`add(E e)`) of entries, and the setting of entries (`set(E e)`) to the underlying list (Unlike Iterator, which just allows removing).